# MSCA seal of excellence

Tags: postdocs, funding, france, marie-curie

I have applied for a Marie Skłodowska-Curie fellowship and, despite receiving a grade of 90%, did not receive it. Although nothing is mentioned in the application, it turns out something called a "seal of excellence" (SoE) exists and is given to people with scores higher than 85%. They claim this seal could be used to acquire funding from other sources.

Unfortunately, except for some hand-wavy stuff about a medical school in the Netherlands and some universities in Germany, there is not a lot of information about what one could achieve with these seals. I have heard from friends that in Italy, more specifically Padova, the university itself can offer to cover your research if you are awarded a SoE.

My question is specifically about France, since I could not find much on the subject: Is it of any use here, and especially in the Île-de-France region?

Comment: Does this help? https://ec.europa.eu/info/research-and-innovation/funding/funding-opportunities/seal-excellence_en

Comment: @Sursula-they- I checked this link, but unfortunately there is essentially nothing said about France...

Comment: I don't think there's any official way to get a postdoc out of a seal of excellence in France. However, you can include it in your CV. Have you tried contacting the French NCP? https://ec.europa.eu/info/funding-tenders/opportunities/portal/screen/support/ncp There are four contacts listed for inquiries about MSCA.